# Saving images read with glReadPixels where alpha value is not one

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

When saving an image using `glReadPixels`, the colors are distorted where their alpha value is less than one.

The surface is managed by QtQuick. With `glGetInteger` I found out there are 8 bits for each channel, including alpha.

I can get a better result, but not perfect, using something like this:

```
for x := 0; x < m.Bounds().Dx(); x++ {
    for y := 0; y < m.Bounds().Dy(); y++ {
        c := m.RGBAAt(x, y)
        w := float64(c.A) / 255
        c.R = uint8(float64(c.R)*w + 255*(1-w) + 0.5)
        c.G = uint8(float64(c.G)*w + 255*(1-w) + 0.5)
        c.B = uint8(float64(c.B)*w + 255*(1-w) + 0.5)
        c.A = 255
    m.SetRGBA(x, y, c)
    }
}
```

I tried to clear the alpha component in OpenGL itself using:

```
s.gl.ClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
s.gl.ColorMask(false, false, false, true)
s.gl.Clear(GL.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
```

Now the result is similar to my manual composing, moreover displayed and the captured image are the same but are still different from (and darker than) what was displayed before.

I'm interested in how OpenGL/Qt uses the alpha channel when displaying the color buffer. Maybe QtQuick composes it with a backing layer?

Comment: Are you familiar with pre-multiplied alpha? Your solution is based on it (though has some superfluous details I cannot explain). However, if you're not sure why it sort of works I get the impression you may not be.

Comment: No, I didn't. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. If I understand correctly, I have to blend the image with a white background. But why? Anyway I tried something, considering the output of glReadPixels as premultiplied but I still cannot get precise results. Also, why this is premultiplied? Can you help me find relevant documentation? Thank you.

Comment: For example, how can the color of labels (RGBA 133,30,30,159) become white (RGB 255,255,255)?

Comment: Most often pre-multiplied alpha is used for alpha compositing. Pre-multiplied alpha blending is associative, which allows more flexiblity. It also avoids issues with filtering transparent pixels; a pixel with **0** alpha should have its RGB color ignored when interpolating between non-transparent pixels. Multiplying RGB by A ahead of time accomplishes that mathematically instead of using something silly like `if (alpha == 0.0) ...`. As for the colors, if the framebuffer is stored using pre-multiplied alpha, then you should be able to simply divide RGB by A to get the correct color.

Comment: This is not the case: in the above example, 133,30,30,159 should become 255,255,255. There must be something other.

Comment: Your final solution to the problem was to use the proper blend function for pre-multiplied alpha `(ONE, ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` - that is how you produce the same results as `(SRC_ALPHA, ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` traditionally does when the source color is already multiplied by alpha. Trying to blend pre-multiplied alpha colors using the traditional blend function will cause alpha to be squared and give the wrong results. _Rather than edit your question to point that out, however, you should write an answer and accept it._

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice the squared alpha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by never changing alpha during drawing. So instead of `gl.BlendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`, I now use `gl.BlendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` and modified the other parameters to get it looking as before.

As Andon M. Coleman pointed out in his comments, this is the same as using pre-multiplied alpha blending. This way, the alpha value of color buffer remains always one and the problem is worked around.

`glBlendFuncSeparate`, which specify pixel arithmetic for RGB and alpha components separately, would have been useful to get the same result.